# Python Boto3 DynamoDB - How to parse map value types?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am storing values in my dynamodb database in this format
`{"user_id":123456789,"user_xp_stats":{"user_level":15,"user_xp":12670}}`
After I request a get_item for specific user's "xp_stats" I get a object like this:
`{ "M" : { "M" : { "user_level" : { "N" : "1" }, "user_xp" : { "N" : "8.1" } } }}`
How should I parse it?

[image: Cloud Console screenshot]

In other words, should I have it as a map or store "user_level" and "user_xp" each separately as a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, should I have it as a map or store "user_level" and "user_xp" each separately as a single value?

Its very difficult to make a call based on this one single example. If your items will usually have `user_level` and `user_xp`, I would keep it as separate attributes.

This gives your more options later on, e.g. you can create [Global Secondary Indices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) later on based on these attributes. Its also easier to read and write as you noticed then a single `map`.